# How to create customise property page for custom navigator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Hi friends I m new to eclipse plugin. I need to create a new custom navigator and depending on the selection of the elements in the navigator i want to display the corresponding property sheet for it. I had gone through various tutorials but m not finding how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: So, which one is this question about: custom navigator or property page?

Comment: Hi, question is about the property page. Basically I need to develop a plug-in which functions like a photo-shop, wherein we have a new project explorer, an editor, properties page. Please can you suggest me some books or tutorials or links for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to provide an Adapter for the model objects added into the custom navigator. The simplest way to do that is to register an Adapter factory extension point something like that:

```
<extension
 point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
  <factory
   adaptableType="the type from the model navigator"
   class="«your adapter factory class»">
  <adapter
    type="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource">
  </adapter>
 </factory>
</extension>
```

If you have the adaptable factory, you could follow the article [Take control of your properties](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had tried the above code it works for me. I need to develop a plug-in which functions like a photo-shop, wherein we have a new project explorer, an editor, properties page. Please can you suggest me some books or tutorials or links for the same. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking at the articles at eclipse.org/resources and vogella.de/eclipse. With a so general question I cannot tell anything more concrete.